Hardware failure with Fujitsu D3307-A12 CP400i 12GB RAID HBA
I have a RAID card that was listed on eBay as Fujitsu D3307-A12 CP400i 12GB RAID HBA, cables and two WD SATA SSD drives connected for testing on Windows PC.
The card was not picked up by Ubuntu box where it was originally inteded so I put it into PC with Gigabyte Z590 Aorus MB. Here it shows as AVAGO MegaRAID SAS adapter.I do not have SAS cables at the moment, but I assume it should support SATA too, if it really is LSI SAS3008.
There is nothing except a short delay during boot, nothing appears about RAID and no prompt to enter configuration, pressing Ctrl-H, Ctrl-R etc does not have effect.
Windows shows the device having hw error. Does this indicate the card is faulty, or should I attempt to flash it or do I miss something else that is obvious to super users?

Events:


Does the answer help? It says having DirectPDMapping enabled on a different MegaRAID adapter caused a "An I/O adapter hardware error has occurred" error, and that disabling DirectPDMapping fixed the error.

@ChesterGillon: Well, I think not because I have tried with and without disks in two different PCs. RAID does not show up during boot. Wouldn't that be a prerequsite?
